# How to add IEEE style bibliography and new chapter in a report file?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, thesis, report

I am currently writing my thesis and I want to have a fully prepared template to just focus in writing. My problem is that I have to use a IEEE style to put my references in my document and I am having problems achieving that. I have seen some videos explaining this using a bibtext file, but when I try this, it does not work at all. By the way, I have a bibtext file with some references already written named biblio_MT. Also, I want to add a new chapter to the document and have it referenced in the table of contents. The new chapter should be called "Anexos", this I could not achieve either. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Defino idioma como español
\usepackage{graphicx} % Para Añadir imagenes
\usepackage{subfigure} %Para las subfiguras
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % Para que el pdf referencie directamente las referencias
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts} %para \textbf y otras cosas
\usepackage{setspace} %sirve para espaciado del documento entre otras cosas
\usepackage{dsfont}% para conjunto entero, reales.
\usepackage{stackrel}%paquete matematico para algunos simbolos
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerados
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

%%%%%%%%% TABLAS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\usepackage{multicol}% Para separar columnas
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{babelbib} %para que las referencias esten en español
\usepackage{listings} %Para agregar codigos
\usepackage{algorithm} %Para escribir pseudocodigos
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} %Para escribir pseudocodigos


%FORMATOS ESPECIFICOS MEMORIA
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} %0 sangria
\spacing{1.15} %Espaciado
%\usepackage{times} %Letra times new Roman
\usepackage{Helvet}
\usepackage{anysize}% Para definir margenes
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2cm}{2.5cm}{2cm}% Controla los márgenes {izquierda}{derecha}{arriba}{abajo}
% IMAGEN DE FONDO
%La opción pages puede ser all (para todo el documento) o some, para algunas partes del documento
%\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
% configuración
%\%backgroundsetup{
%   scale=.2, %escala de la imagen, es recomendable que sea del mismo tamaño que el pdf
%   color=black, %fondo a usar para transparencia
%   opacity=0.2, %nivel de transparencia
%   angle=0, %en caso de querer una rotación
%   contents={%
%       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Figuras/Logo_Udec.jpg} %nombre de la imagen a utilizar como fondo
%   }}

%%Tratando de poner python
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % size of fonts used for the code
  breaklines=true,                 % automatic line breaking only at whitespace
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
}





%Formato del titulo de los capitulos
\usepackage{titlesec} %paquete para cambiar el formato de los titulos

\newcommand{\bigrule}{\titlerule[0.5mm]}
{\vspace{-5cm}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display] % cambiamos el formato de los capítulos
    {\bfseries\Huge} % por defecto se usarán caracteres de tamaño \Huge en negrita
    {% contenido de la etiqueta
        %\titlerule % línea horizontal
        \filright % texto alineado a la derecha
        \Large\chaptertitlename\ % "Capítulo" o "Apéndice" en tamaño \Large en lugar de \Huge
        \Large\thechapter} % número de capítulo en tamaño \Large
    {0mm} % espacio mínimo entre etiqueta y cuerpo
    {\filright} % texto del cuerpo alineado a la derecha
    [\vspace{0.5mm} \bigrule] % después del cuerpo, dejar espacio vertical y trazar línea horizontal gruesa

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Numeracion de paginas en esquina superior derecha
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% primera pagina de un capitulo
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice General}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Índice de Figuras}

%Redefino algunos casos como tablas, referencias
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{ \text{\Large Cap\'itulo 7} \\ Referencias}
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Fuente: {#1}} } % Para poderle añadir la fuente a las figuras 

%    \NoBgThispage % para evitar el logo udec de fondo en la primera pagina
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
        \sffamily{\LARGE \textbf{UNIVERSIDAD DE CONCEPCIÓN}} %\\[-240pt]    
        \\
        \sffamily{\normalsize FACULTAD DE INGENIER\'IA}
        \\
        \sffamily{\normalsize DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIER\'IA INDUSTRIAL}
        \vfill
        %\scalebox{0.37}{\includegraphics{Figuras/Logo_Udec.jpg}} % Para añadir el logo de la escuela
        \sffamily{\normalsize \hfill Profesor Patrocinante: $\hspace{2.25cm}$ \\ \hfill \textbf{Maichel M. Aguayo} $\hspace{2.65cm}$ }\\[-35pt]
        \scalebox{0.37}{\includegraphics{Logo_Udec.jpg}} % Para añadir el logo de la escuela
        \vfill  
        \sffamily{ \hfill Informe de Memoria de T\'itulo $\hspace{.9cm}$ \\ \hfill Para optar al T\'itulo de: $\hspace{2.165cm}$}\\[-20pt]
        \vfill
        \sffamily{\normalsize  \hfill \textbf{Ingeniero Civil Industrial} $\hspace{1.5cm}$ }\\[50pt]
        \vfill
        \sffamily{\LARGE Problema de Ruteo de Veh\'iculos con Múltiples Depósitos, Múltiples Productos, Split Delivery y Fixed Destination}\\[100pt]
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \sffamily{Concepci\'on, Agosto del 2018 \hfill Gonzalo Gálvez Bobadilla}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\ \\
\vspace{5cm}

        \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \sffamily{UNIVERSIDAD DE CONCEPCI\'ON \hfill Profesor Patrocinante:}\textmd 
        \\
        \sffamily{Facultad de Ingenier\'ia \hfill Maichel M. Aguayo}
        \\
        \sffamily{Departamento de Ingenier\'ia Industrial}
        \vfill
        \begin{center}
            %\scalebox{0.37}{\includegraphics{IPN.eps}} % Para añadir el logo de la escuela
            \vfill
            % Genera un espacio
            \sffamily{\LARGE Problema de Ruteo de Veh\'iculos con Múltiples Depósitos, Múltiples Productos, Split Delivery y Fixed Destination}\\[60pt]
            \vfill
            \text{\Large Gonzalo Eduardo Gálvez Bobadilla}
            \vfill
            \sffamily{Informe de Memoria de T\'itulo \\ Para optar al T\'itulo de}\\[-40pt]
            \vfill
            \sffamily{\Large{Ingeniero Civil Industrial}}\\[50pt]
            \vfill
            \sffamily{\Large{Agosto 2018}}\\[10pt]
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}




\newpage
\chapter*{Agradecimientos}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Agradecimientos}
\begin{quotation}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent \textit{En primer lugar, quiero agradecer a mi madre por todo su amor incondicional y por siempre haberse mantenido firme, incluso en los momentos más difíciles.}\\ \\
    \noindent \textit{A mis hermanas, por todo lo que han hecho por mí, que es imposible explicar en palabras.}\\

    \noindent \textit{A mi cuñado, por guiarme desde pequeño en el basto mundo de la ingeniería industrial.}\\

    \noindent \textit{A mi profesor guía, por todo los conocimientos que me entregó y por jugársela por mí.}\\

    \noindent \textit{A mis amigos, por estar siempre ahí, en las buenas y en las malas.}




\end{quotation} 
\newpage
\chapter*{Resumen}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumen}
\begin{quotation}
    El presente trabajo aborda un problema de ruteo de vehículos con múltiples productos, múltiples depósitos, \emph{split delivery} y \emph{fixed destination}. Para este problema se plantea un modelo de programación matemática, el cual fue resuelto en \emph{IBM Cplex Studio IDE 12.7.1} y una heurística diseñada en \emph{Python 3.5}. Se utilizaron instancias de \emph{Coredeaus}, obtenidas desde el sitio web \emph{Networking and Emerging Optimization}, para probar el funcionamiento tanto del modelo como de la heurística. Además de propone una instancia real basada en logística humanitaria, la cual es resuelta con el modelo matemático.\\

Al comparar las soluciones encontradas por el modelo matemático, con las encontradas por la heurística, se observa que esta última encuentra soluciones 13\% peores, sin embargo su tiempo de respuesta es un 98.6\% más rápido. Esto caracteriza a la heurística como un buen método para encontrar soluciones de rápidas.\\

En futuros temas de investigación, se puede analizar la posibilidad de modelar este problema siendo de tipo multi-objetivo, considerando por ejemplo, maximizar la satisfacción de los clientes.        
\end{quotation}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice de Figuras} % para que aparezca en el indice de contenidos
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice de Tablas} % para que aparezca en el indice de contenidos
\listoftables % Genera el Índice de tablas
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introducción}
Hola como estas, esto es un test a ver si se pueden inclutir las referencias \cite{varela} 
\chapter{Revisión literatura}
%\include{Descripcion_Problema}
\chapter{Modelos matematicos}
\chapter{Heuristica}
\chapter{Resultados}
\chapter{Conclusiones}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{7.\hspace{0.5cm }Referencias}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio_MT}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer shows a minimal code using `report` class (using other classes e.g. `article`, `memoir`, is not so much different). From this answer you can basically know how to:

1. Create table of contents
2. Create citations for references
3. Create citations for chapters, sections, etc.

**The code (e.g. main.tex)**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee]{biblatex} % using biblatex with style style=ieee
\addbibresource{reference.bib} % file inside which references are stored 
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % optional for adding suitable perfix to citations of chapters, sections, figures ...etc
%
\begin{document}
%
\tableofcontents % Creating table of contents
%
\chapter{Reference and Citation} \label{ch:reference}
%
\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
In order to cite one reference, you can use cite command like this \cite{Doe_2020}. You can also cite two references like this \cite{Doe_2020,Tenis_2000}.
%
\section{Citing previous sections} \label{sec:citing}
This is to show how to cite previous sections. The references can be found in section \ref{sec:intro}.

\section{Using cleveref package} \label{sec:using}
In section \ref{sec:intro}, you had to write "section" before ref command. Using cleveref, you can cite directly like this \cref{sec:intro} and \cref{sec:citing}. You can even cite two sections directly like this \cref{sec:intro,sec:citing} or even multiple sections in the same time like this \cref{sec:intro,sec:citing,sec:using}.

The same apply for chapters and figures. For example, the first chapter can be cited like this \cref{ch:reference}.

\printbibliography % list of references is printed here
\end{document}
```

As you can see, citing sections, chapters, even figures, etc, is related to creating `\label{something}` which after each sections, chapters, that we want to cite later. Then, in place that you want to add citation to these, you just use the command `\ref{something}` or the more advanced `\cref{something}`.

Chapters are added by the command `\chapter{name of chapter}` and they are referenced automatically, along with sections, in the table of contents by the command `\tableofcontents` in the desired place in the document, normally at the beginning after the report title.

**For the example explained here, you should create a `bib` file in the same working folder that contains the tex file called `reference.bib` with the following contents**

```
@Book{Doe_2020,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {John Wiley},
  title     = {Differential equations : an introduction to modern methods and applications},
  year      = {2020},
  address   = {New Jersey},
  isbn      = {9780471651413},
  keywords  = {Differential equations},
  language  = {In English},
}

@Article{Tenis_2000,
  author  = {Michael Tenis},
  journal = {Jounal of Energy},
  title   = {New article about something},
  year    = {2000},
  month   = aug,
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {66--88},
  volume  = {2},
}
```

As shown above, for citing references or (bibliography), used in main tex file by the command `\cite{ref-key}`, you need first to create a separate `bib` file with a list of desired references that you want to add in your report. Note that there are many types of references that you can add (e.g. book, article, conference, etc) each with the proper type format. Some bib managers can assist you in the process of creating bib files (e.g. [JabRef](https://www.fosshub.com/JabRef.html)).

The output you obtain by compiling is like this

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Your answer did not solve my situation, but certainly helps a lot, thanks and greetings from Chile, take care.